# What is the correct fields in `time_partitioning` for GCSToBigQueryOperator in Airflow

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow, google-cloud-composer

So I'm working with the Airflow Operator `GCSToBigQueryOperator` and I know the following for sure:

```
time_partitioning={'field': 'date', 'type': 'DAY'}
```

This works as it should. However when I try to add in `expiration / require_partition_filter` something like:

```
time_partitioning={'field': 'date', 'type': 'DAY', 'expiration': 365, 'require_partition_filter': True}
```

The output that I get is a partitioned table based on `date` and partitioned by `DAY` but nothing afterwards. I'm wondering if my syntax is incorrect, I've tried looking for examples of this or see what the syntax is but the airflow documentation refers back to the API.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated as I'm unsure of the syntax for this would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you didn't set the correct configuration for `expiration` param, according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquery/latest/google.cloud.bigquery.table.TimePartitioning), the fields are :

```
type_
field
expiration_ms
require_partition_filter
```

In your `Airflow` operator, use the following `Dict` :

```py
time_partitioning={
     'field': 'date', 
     'type': 'DAY', 
     'expiration_ms': 365, 
     'require_partition_filter': True
}
```

Comment: You're right, I changed the `expiration` param and was able to get it to work. Thank you!!